# :focus not working for the input control scss

Tags: css, sass

I am using scss, i am trying create a floating label without javascript. 
Here i am having an text box and label inside a div with class name `form-type-textfield` and `form-type-email`.what i am trying to do here is that whenever the focus is on textbox, i am moving the label upwards.

but it seems like the `:focus` is not working for me,but when i use `:hover` its working fine, but i want to apply the css on :focus.

What am i doing wrong here?
 my html structure looks like this.

```
<div>
    <label>Label</label>
    <input type="textbox">
</div>
```

css

```
     .form-type-textfield input:focus,.form-type-email input:focus{
        label{
            transform: translateY(-25px);        
            -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
            -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
            transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
            font-size: 16px !important;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that goes wrong? In your current example, there is no `:focus`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `div` has not a `:focus` state but you can check if any of its descendents is focused using the `:focus-within` [pseudoclass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```
.form-type-textfield:focus-within,   
.form-type-email:focus-within {

    label{
       transform: translateY(-25px);        
       -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
       -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
       transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
       font-size: 16px !important;
    }
}
```

Alternatively if your label follows the `input` on the markup you could use a sibling combinator to target those labels e.g.

```
:focus + label { ... }
```

Comment: Hi i had missed the `input` in the post, i have updated.

Comment: that style is now looking for a label as a child of an input. It can't work

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you're trying to use :focus on an `<div>` element? As far as I know, :focus only works on elements which take a user input/action, such as `<a>` and `<input>` tags. This would explain why :hover works but :focus doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the updated post - it looks like you're using nesting and targeting the label as a child of the input? This will be an issue, since the input and label are (probably) siblings?

Comment: You will need to change the structure of your SCSS then, as you're currently targeting a child element. Use the sibling selector (+) or a class name (I'd imagine a class name would work well as this seems like something you may be repeating throughout the site?).